# Hex to ASCII showing different result to correct PHP implementaiton

Tags: java, hex, ascii, bitcoin

I needed a method that would convert hex to ascii, and most seem to be a variation of the following:

```
public String hexToAscii(String hex) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i += 2){
        String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
        sb.append((char)decimal);
        temp.append(decimal);
    }    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The idea is to look at

```
hexToAscii("51d37bdd871c9e1f4d5541be67a6ab625e32028744d7d4609d0c37747b40cd2d");
```

If I print the result out, I get

```
-Í@{t7?`Ô×D?2^b«¦g¾AUM??Ý{ÓQ.
```

This is not the result I am needing though.  A friend got the correct result in PHP which was the string reverse of the following:

```
QÓ{Ý‡žMUA¾g¦«b^2‡D×Ô`7t{@Í-
```

There are clearly characters that his hexToAscii function is encoding whereas mine is not.
Not really sure why this is the case, but how can I implement this version in Java?

Comment: There are two separate questions here, one about the ordering and another about the characters. Debug this method and verify that it's getting the string (and processing it) in the expected order. Regarding the output, your issue is mostly likely just that your terminal isn't displaying high-bit characters correctly; question marks and square boxes are classic substitutions.

Comment: Sry, I don't have a question about ordering.  his is out of order because he used a reverse method.  Also, my terminal can print this just fine.  Also, the sha256 of the two are different.

Comment: I agree this seems like a problem with whatever you are using to display the output. In a quick test, Ideone displays it correctly: http://ideone.com/40CyOL

Comment: I'm still going with the terminal, because you get the correct number of characters (meaning that it's not UTF-8 confusion), and all of the characters being replaced with question marks are the special-special characters. When you say "the SHA-256", are you talking about the final strings? Are you sure that they're in the same order and that you're not comparing the bytes in a 16-bit-Unicode Java string to an 8-bit PHP string?

Comment: Are you sure? What is '‡'? It isn't found anywhere in the ideone.com output. I just looked at   sha256(hexToAscii("51d37bdd871c9e1f4d5541be67a6ab625e32028744d7d4609d0c37747b40cd2d")) vs sha256("QÓ{Ý‡žMUA¾g¦«b^2‡D×Ô`7t{@Í-")

Answer (score 0):

How about trying like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hex = "51d37bdd871c9e1f4d5541be67a6ab625e32028744d7d4609d0c37747b40cd2d";
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
        String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
        output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input string is `in`, I would use a method like this

```
public static byte[] decode(String in) {
  if (in != null) {
    in = in.trim();
    List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    char[] chArr = in.toCharArray();

    int t = 0;
    while (t + 1 < chArr.length) {
      String token = "" + chArr[t] + chArr[t + 1];
      // This subtracts 128 from the byte value.
      int b = Byte.MIN_VALUE
          + Integer.valueOf(token, 16);
      bytes.add((byte) b);
      t += 2;
    }
    byte[] out = new byte[bytes.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); ++i) {
      out[i] = bytes.get(i);
    }
    return out;
  }
  return new byte[] {};
}
```

And then you could use it like this

```
new String(decode("51d37bdd871c9e1f4d5541be67a6ab625e"
  +"32028744d7d4609d0c37747b40cd2d"))
```